# How to make vs code print output in external console?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, console, console-application, rust-cargo

I wanted to make an rust application which will show spinning cube in console. So I need to print stuff in console but whenever I run my code the result is printed in integrated vscode window. How can I make vscode print result in console?

[image: The picture of console]

Comment: I think this might be a question of vscode rather than rust. Besides, how about just exec `cargo run` in an external terminal?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `launch.json` file in a `.vscode` folder at the root of your (cargo) project.
This file determines what happens when you "debug" or "run" your project from VSCode's perspective. Assuming you have CodeLLDB installed (available as a [VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb)), you can put this in your `launch.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Cargo run",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "run",
                ]
            },
            "args": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal",
        },
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Cargo test",
            "cargo": {
                "args": [
                    "test",
                    "--no-run",
                ]
            },
            "args": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal",
        }
    ]
}
```

The `"console":` field tells VSCode whether to run your configuration in an external terminal (`"externalTerminal"`) or internally (`"integratedConsole"`).

Side note: you can also hide your program's output entirely by using `"internalConsole"` (of course this isn't useful for programs that prompt the user for input in the console, but it is an option!).

The biggest issue with simply specifying `"externalTerminal"` for using an external terminal is that it will not reuse the same window/terminal for multiple runs. It will instead say `"Press any key to continue . . ."` (atleast on Windows), making you close that & open a new terminal with F5 on subsequent runs/debugs.

[Here's what VSCode looks like for me when I do this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swHQ6.png)